# how to get a multiple outputs function called in cython

Tags: python, c++, cython

I'm writing a function in cython (to optimize a python function) that uses another cython optimized function which returns a and b. I want to use a and b in the second function to do some calculation and I DON'T KNOW how! Should I use something like an extended type (class, struct???) or there is another way to do it? here are my python function (I'm not an expert but it works very well):

```
for i in range(n_max):  
    output     = func.func(indata,i) // My tuple [2]
    tmp1       = output[0]
    tmp2       = output[1] 
....other calculations
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Passing a struct is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a C struct you write yourself. Easier, if you are compiling using C++ you can use the C++ `std::pair`. The Cython syntax for it is

```
from libcpp.vector cimport pair

cdef pair[int, int] myPair2
```